# What is the meaning of a period in between of a file name of a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript

I came across a filename "Signin.screen.js", what is the meaning/role of the first period in the filename?

Comment: That's impossible for us to tell without any context. Perhaps it would be better to ask the author?

Comment: it's just a way to keep order, maybe there are other javascript files with the same name prefix, like Signin.footer.js or others. it's like namespacing

Comment: @GrafiCode, you are right, there are many files with the ".screen" part in their name. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it's just to make it easier to read the file names because of how they're organized in that particular project. Like "hey everything here is used for this screen"

You can use Find in Files to look for any code that uses "screen.js" but it's most likely not being used in the code.